# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't start on Ubuntu after Change the boot Java runtime

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Before, my IntelliJ ran well. But I used java 6 , so my project could not run with gradle.
I switched java to version 8 with the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` .
I checked `java -version`  was `1.8.0_312`. It's OK, but in IntelliJ, the Java still had version 6. Then, I changed java version  in IntelliJ with:

> *From the main menu, select Help | Find Action or press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.***
>
> *Find and select the Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE action.*
>
> *Select the desired runtime and click OK.*

And restarted IntelliJ, which could not be opened again. I tried to remove and install it again as well as removing java and installing it again too, but neither did work.
When I run `./idea.sh`, I get the following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Archived non-system classes are disabled because the java.system.class.loader property is specified (value = "com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader"). To use archived non-system classes, this property must not be set
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.intellij.idea.Main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

---

Now, I'm not even able to "[change JRE in intelliJ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)" as [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72067909/intellij-idea-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu-after-change-the-boot-java-runtime#comment127350005_72067909) any more.

Comment: It is not recommended to change JRE used by the IDE process. Please switch it to JBR (JetBrains Runtime) as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under .

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#jdk. on how to set up a project JDK

Comment: For me, the solution was downloading the correct file. On installing, I clicked on `Download .tar.gz (Linux ARM64)` instead of `Download .tar.gz (Linux)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same issue working on windows.

When you check IntelliJ's log (idea.log file) you can find a entry for the change you've made with its 'reset' option.

For me it was: (emphasis is mine)

> 2022-08-08 09:47:47,906 [ 594730]   WARN -
> Downloader.RuntimeChooserPaths - Set custom boot runtime to:
> C:\Data\Java\jdk-17.0.3.1 in the
> **C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\idea64.exe.jdk**.
> On errors, please **remove the .jdk file**

You find the log files are stored at:

Linux: `~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/log`

Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\log`

macOS: `~/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using a lower version of JRE for running the IntelliJ that is compiled in a higher version. to fix this you can change the JRE path in the following file(or you can delete the file also).

```
~/.config/JetBrains/<product><version>/idea.jdk
```

eg:`~/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/idea.jdk`

Ref: [IntelliJ Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#e8793cb9)

Answer (score 0):

Converting the comment by [the author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18351457/ph%E1%BB%A5ng-ph%E1%BA%A1m-v%C4%83n) from May 2 at 4:22 to an answer.

The issue was resolved by changing the JRE path in this file: `/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.1/idea.jdk`