# INTELLIJ is crashing after I "changed boot runtime"

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, crash

I wanted to use JDK-11 on my intellij. So I changed java boot runtime following these [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html). Now my Intellij is crashing without opening. I am using MAC.

[Crash Report.](https://ideone.com/k3CaFB)

Closest I have found on internet with my issue is this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72067909/intellij-idea-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu-after-change-the-boot-java-runtime), but this is for ubuntu. ( PS. There is MAC OS solution as well mentioned, but it is not working for me, since there is no `Jetbrains` directory in my `~/Library/Logs/` directory. I don't know how to proceed on the steps without JetBrains in Logs. )[image: You can see there is no JetBrains inside the Library/Logs directory]

I can not even change back the JRE since IDEA is not even opening.

This might be completely unrelating to the question, but I have installed openjdk 11.0.19 installed via homeBrew on my MAC.

**UPDATE**

There is no `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains` in the path.

[image: no jetbrains found in application support]

Answer (score 3):

In macOS, there are two Library folders. In the SSD/HDD root and in the user's home dir. Most probably you're checking the SSD one. Please try to:

1. Open the OS Bash
2. Execute open `~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains` It will open the needed folder in Finder.
3. Navigate to the needed IDE version and delete `<product>.jdk` file. It will reverse back to the default runtime.

Also, instead of changing the runtime for the IDE, try [changing the project SDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#change-project-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to change the Java runtime for IntelliJ in the first place because [Change the boot Java runtime of the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) explicitly says

> **Changing the boot Java runtime may cause unexpected problems. Do not change it unless you were specifically asked to do so by JetBrains support**.

and

> The runtime for IntelliJ IDEA is not the same runtime used for your applications. Define an SDK for each of your projects, which includes the necessary development and runtime environment.

and I think what you wanted to do is just this: use a specific Java version for your projects.

Anyway, that page later has the information that you probably need:

> The path to the selected runtime is stored in the idea.jdk or idea64.jdk file in the IntelliJ IDEA configuration directory. If there are problems with the selected runtime, you can delete this file to revert to the default runtime.

And that links to [Configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#cc446e5e) which says that on Mac the settings are stored in

> ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/

which is probably (if you're using the current version)

> ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1

and remove the "idea.jdk" and "idea64.jdk" files.

Comment: I am sharing another screen shot regarding `~/Library/Application Support/` , there is no JetBrains either. I had checked that link on Jetbrains docs. but there is no directory at all. I have updated my question, Please have look at that.